# How to pass list of values as a parameter to OleDbCommand

Tags: c#, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

I want to execute query

```
SELECT id, name FROM MyTable WHERE (id, name) IN ((1, 'One'), (2, 'Two'))
```

using `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand`. Is it possible to pass the contents of `IN` clause as a parameter to command? If yes then what value should I pass a parameter value? List, IEnumerable or something else? If not then is it possible to pass the list of single values like for query

```
SELECT id, name FROM MyTable WHERE id IN (1, 2)
```

Comment: why not just assign the whole of the IN Clause to a string in code behind and then make your query this "SELECT id, name FROM MyTable WHERE (id, name) IN " + InClauseString

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-a-sql-in-clause

Comment: Just to note that your first snippet is not a valid SQL Syntax

Comment: @Steve it works for Oracle

Comment: @Demarsch really? I didn't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as I know you can't. I was trying something similar in the past and the only way I found was to create an stored procedure which receives a comma separated string and create the query dynamically, calling `sp_execute` at the end with the resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/231217/Parameters-SqlCommand-vs-OledbCommand-and-OdbcComm

You would be responsible for writing the SQL of course.
SQL does not take anonymous objects for an IN parameter.  You must specify what you are looking for in a single field.

```
Select * from table where field in (1,2,3) --Assuming field is an integer
```

For example.